# Mediaelementjs doesn't work on Firefox

Tags: html, nginx, mediaelement.js, mediaelement

I'm creating a server for streaming videos. I use nginx and rtmp module.
But when I play video in my web, it works fine with Chrome and edge but Firefox is'nt.

Firefox shows this and I don't know why:

[image]

Here is my html file:

```
<video width="640" height="360" id="player1">
    <source type="video/rtmp" src="rtmp://myserver:myport/livestreaming/live" />
    <source type="application/x-mpegURL" src="http://myserver/livestreaming/live/index.m3u8" />
</video>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/demo/hls_streams.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadStream(url) {
        $('video')[0].player.setSrc(url);
        $('video')[0].player.play();
    }
</script>
<script>
    $('video').mediaelementplayer({
        success: function(media, node, player) {
            $('#' + node.id + '-mode').html('mode: ' + media.pluginType);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Did you find any solution?